# What is the correct tools directory to install DotNet so that you can build with MSBuild on Ubuntu?

Tags: .net, ubuntu, msbuild, azure-pipelines

I'm using Azure Pipelines with the ubuntu-latest VM.  I am installing DotNet 7 through the InstallDotNet task.  I am running MSBuild, and receiving an error that DotNet7 is not present.

Switching to dotnet build - the build runs successfully - which implies to me that MSBuild and DotNet Build look at different locations for their tools.

**Error Log: **
/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1232,5): error MSB3971: The reference assemblies for ".NETFramework,Version=v7.0" were not found. You might be using an older .NET SDK to target .NET 5.0 or higher. Update Visual Studio and/or your .NET SDK.

**DotNet7 install log:**
Tool to install: .NET Core sdk version 7.x.
Found version 7.0.400 in channel 7.0 for user specified version spec: 7.x
Version 7.0.400 was not found in cache.
Getting URL to download .NET Core sdk version: 7.0.400.
Detecting OS platform to find correct download package for the OS.
/home/vsts/work/_tasks/UseDotNet_b0ce7256-7898-45d3-9cb5-176b752bfea6/2.226.0/externals/get-os-distro.sh
get-os-distro: Error: Distribution specific OS name and version could not be detected: UName = Linux
Primary:linux-x64
Legacy:-x64
Detected platform (Primary): linux-x64
Detected platform (Legacy): -x64
Downloading: https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/dbfe6cc7-dd82-4cec-b267-31ed988b1652/c60ab4793c3714be878abcb9aa834b63/dotnet-sdk-7.0.400-linux-x64.tar.gz
Extracting downloaded package /home/vsts/work/_temp/69b9d9ab-bd0f-4bfa-bf4d-ffe6357c4567.
Extracting archive
/usr/bin/tar xC /home/vsts/work/_temp/4f0cd099-0e01-4eab-82d0-de74f4cfbe98 -f /home/vsts/work/_temp/69b9d9ab-bd0f-4bfa-bf4d-ffe6357c4567
Successfully installed .NET Core sdk version 7.0.400.
Creating global tool path and pre-pending to PATH.
Finishing: Install .NET Core SDK

Comment: Is your application using .NET, or .NET Framework? They are different things and you aren't going to be able to build .NET Framework applications on Ubuntu. In fact, there *is no* .NET Framework 7.

Comment: How is the standalone version of MSBuild being installed on your build host machine? By installing Mono? (Note that the `dotnet` tool has an embedded version of `msbuild`. Yes, the standalone `msbuild` and the `dotnet msbuild` look at different locations for runtimes and frameworks.)

Comment: @DanielMann It is .NET, not .NETFramework.  Good point of clarification.

Comment: @JonathanDodds Interesting, that might explain why running dotnet msbuild works for us, but MSBuild doesn't.  I assumed it was by installing mono, but haven't confirmed.  It is whatever comes by default in Azure Pipelines Ubuntu-latest VM.